# Android unit testing with Robolectrics and ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, actionbarsherlock, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric to test my LoginActivity class. I'm using ActionBarSherlock and Robolectric tests fail on getSupportActionBar() line. Here's my code and trace.

LoginActivity.java

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends SherlockActivity {
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        ...
...
..
 }
```

LoginActivityTest.java

```
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
..
.
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {

     private LoginActivity activity;
     @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        }

   @Test @Config(reportSdk = 10)
    public void shouldActivityCreated() throws Exception {
           activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().get();
           assertNotNull(activity);
    }
}
```

When I try to JUnit test, I got failure with trace :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1003)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:915)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.initActionBar(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:138)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.getActionBar(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:128)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.getSupportActionBar(SherlockActivity.java:37)
    at auth.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:92)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:116)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:256)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:111)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:123)
    at LoginActivityTest.shouldActivityCreated(LoginActivityTest.java:85)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:234)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

---

After research, I found this : https://gist.github.com/marsucsb/6059760
I created these 3 classes, and write necessary registration & unregistration codes in my setup function in my test class, I cannot set contentview for shadowed mActivity : 
shadowOf(mActivity).setContentView(contentView);

I'm using Eclipse and Robolectric 2.2-jar-with-dependencies

Do you have any idea to skip this ActionBarSherlock error while testing?
Thanks.

Comment: You are using `reportSdk = 10` in your test. Do you have the correct theme set up for API 10? Maybe `res/values-v11` contains a Sherlock theme but `res/values` does not?

Comment: @Nachi I'm not familiar with these style files. How can I check that I have the correct theme setup for API 10? Should I look at res/values/style.xml ? By the way, minSdk : 8 , targetSdk . 17 for my project

Comment: Post all your style.xml files. These should be under `res/values` and any `res/values-vXX` folders.

Comment: hello, I created that gist on github. Its not necessary for Robolectric 2.2. Your problem has to do with the theme you are extending from. When you use Actionbarsherlock,  Have you tried running your app on a gingerbread device? Also see here: https://github.com/marsucsb/simple-robolectric/blob/master/res/values/styles.xml how I extend from Theme.AppCompat? You have to do something similar.

Comment: Here's my `code res/values/style.xml` gist : [link](https://gist.github.com/ersentekin/d9006709d4ff7207e08b) I tried to remove `code @style/..` from parent value, but it didn't work. I got a values-v14 style.xml too looks so similar. What dou you think? @Nachi @Marco

Comment: The style looks fine. I'd move "noAnimTheme" block below the theme declaration. The way you extend from the sherlock theme looks fine. Are you doing the same in your values-v14 style.xml file?

Comment: Yes @Marco it is same as style.xml

Comment: I was able to solve a similar problem by modifying https://gist.github.com/marsucsb/6059760 to use `mActivity.getWindow().setContentView(view);` see the gist at https://gist.github.com/justinmuller/8025465

Comment: @justinmuller thats the exact solution. can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262336/robolectric-actionbar-hide-returns-null/20663867#20663867), [here is a Gist](https://gist.github.com/justinmuller/8025465) that takes @Xian's [Gist](https://gist.github.com/xian/5052673) with a suggestion from [marsucsb](https://gist.github.com/marsucsb/6059760) and modifies it to work with Robolectric 2.2+

To answer this particular question, `shadowOf(mActivity)` is no longer available in Robolectric 2.2+, so `mActivity.getWindow().setContentView(view)` should be used instead of `shadowOf(mActivity).setContentView(view)`