# Robolectric: actionBar.hide() returns Null

Tags: android, junit, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, robolectric

I'm new to Android unit testing and I'm using Robolectric as a testing framework. I use Robolectric 2.2.

I'm trying to test an activity which is like that :

```
public class LoginActivity extends SherlockActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

ActionBar abs = getSupportActionBar();
abs.hide();
}
```

and here's my test class :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {

@Before 
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", "/sdcard");
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().get();
}

@Test
public void should_loginActivity_created() throws Exception {

    assertNotNull(activity);

}
```

I'm getting this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  
at auth.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:119)
```

This line refers to 
    abs.hide();

NOTE : I tried [Xian's Gist](https://gist.github.com/xian/5052673) and it did not work.

Also I try to create ShadowSherlockActivity like [this](https://gist.github.com/ersentekin/7689335) But I have no idea how to use this shadow class to create activity like :

```
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().get();
```

NOTE 2 : I try to use Robolectric Snapshot 2.3 but it did not solved.

Thanks.

Comment: You should look at the https://gist.github.com/marsucsb/6059760 fork of Xian's Gist. Calling ActionBarSherlock.registerImplementation in @Before might help

Comment: @JustinMuller I tried this Gist but I cannot call setContentView method in ActionBarSherlockRobolectric.java

Comment: Instead of `shadowOf(mActivity).setContentView(contentView)` you can set the `contentView` directly via `mActivity.getWindow().setContentView(view)`

Comment: @JustinMuller you're totally right! It worked as I expected. Is this setContentView error occur cause of using the real PhoneWindow of Android in Robolectric 2 ?

Comment: Yes, as of Robolectric 2 (https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/commit/800afc9247b261e06793c12909181e7f03c14fba) ShadowActivity#setContentView(View) is no longer needed and has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ersentekin and I worked out in the comments, here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/justinmuller/8025465) that takes @Xian's [Gist](https://gist.github.com/xian/5052673) with a suggestion from [marsucsb](https://gist.github.com/marsucsb/6059760) and modifies it to work with Robolectric 2.2+

Answer (score 1):

Have u added the android:theme in your androidmanifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
```

Comment: Yes, nothing has changed

Comment: have u made ur activity full screen in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: If you mean that : `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`
No, I did not.